# Passing Windows authentication between client and server application

Tags: windows, client-server, windows-authentication

I have a server application communicating with clients using Boost::Asio.  I can assume that both server and client are running within the same data center so encrypting the connection is not strictly needed (I think, not sure).  Both server and client currently run on Windows platforms.

Now I want to add restrictions to the client applications, but I want to reuse Windows authentication.  In the client application I can easily obtain the user name and group information, but I need to pass this to the server so the server can look up in its configuration tables which user is allowed to see what kind of information.
In the

How can I design this without having to implement my own authentication, without replacing Boost::Asio by a proprietary Windows technology (Android and iOS clients will be added later, and will have an Android/iOS-specific authentication mechanism, like DeviceId) and still preventing rogue clients from connecting as an incorrect/unauthenticated user?

- Do I have to use encrypted connections (and can I do this with Boost::Asio)?
- Do I have to use another authentication mechanism (and is there a portable library for that)?

Comment: I think you'd have to use the SSPI context management functions, e.g., see [Establishing a Secure Connection with Authentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375403(v=vs.85).aspx) on MSDN.  That depends on the client and server being in the same domain (or domains with a suitable trust relationship) though.  Failing that, the only other option is the traditional model, asking the user for a password.

Comment: (Either way, best practice is to encrypt even for traffic within a data center.  Looks like Boost::Asio includes SSL support, so that shouldn't be a problem.)